# PHPWord - How to render word formula into html

Tags: php, ms-word, phpword

I have a MS Word with table content with formula/equation like this:

> Gabriel, Amanda, Lucas e Joelma estão fazendo uma competição para ver quem tem mais figurinhas do álbum da Copa do mundo. Gabriel conseguiu completar 1/5, Amanda 9/10, Lucas colou em seu álbum 7/8, e Joelma 1/2. O ganhador da competição foi

My code is like this right now:

```
$phpword = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($file["tmp_name"]);
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpword, 'HTML');
$xmlWriter = new \PhpOffice\Common\XMLWriter(\PhpOffice\Common\XMLWriter::STORAGE_MEMORY, './', \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::hasCompatibility());

$contentHTML = $objWriter->getContent();

preg_match_all('/<table>(.*?)<\/table>/s', $contentHTML, $tables);
array_splice($tables[0], 0, 1);

foreach ($tables[0] as $key => $table) {
preg_match_all('/<tr>(.*?)<\/tr>/s', $table, $questionTables);

  foreach ($questionTables as $key2 => $questionTable) {
        // table content 

  }
}
```

Now I can get all text and image, but not the formula. It is possible to render this? And transform formula into image or base64?

Comment: By formula you mean 1/5, 9/10 etc? Could it be an encoding issue?

Comment: @Vladan exactly. this 1/5, 9/10 don't render.

Comment: If these are fractions that Word has AutoCorrected to look "nicer", then I think you'll need to ascertain the font and ANSI/Unicode value of such characters. Maybe put them in a "look up table" of some kind. Check the Word content for such combinations and, when found, substitute the "ugly" version (such as in the Block Quote in the question) for your code...